# App crash when i click copy or cut options in the searchBar textfield

Tags: ios, crash, textfield, searchbar

In the options the paste and define was OK , but when i click the copy or cut it will crash. I tried to deleted all code except about the search bar , but it did not work on too.and I tried to override the textfield method but the search bar subviews did not contain a UITextField
this is my code

```
_searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:self.topBar.bounds];
    [_searchBar setPlaceholder:LS(@"Search", @"")];
    [_searchBar setDelegate:self];

    _searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    _searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;

    if( _scopeButtonTitles ) {
        _searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = _scopeButtonTitles;
        _searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    }

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [_searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    _searchResultsAvailable = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
     self.loadingTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@%@",LS(@"Searching", @""),self.title?self.title:@"",@"..."];
    _searchResultsAvailable = YES;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    _searchResultsAvailable = NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had debuted the bug many times, and found the error in my app.
It just need to rewrite the copy and cut method for the searchBar.
After I rewrite the methods the bug had gone